# How can the output power of a Yaesu FT101E be increased?

Tags: electronics, theory

I have a Yaesu FT101E which has low output because the final 6JS6C valves are old. If i increase the plate voltage on the final tubes from 600 to 800 VDC  by changing the mains transformer tapping from 240 V to 220 V will that increase the output power ? What else would that do ?

Comment: Are you sure that a 9% increase in AC mains voltage will produce a 33% increase in plate voltage?

Comment: I don't know how tubes age, but as far as I'd guess, it's both air diffusion into the tube's vacuum (which leads to oxidized getter, and plate surfaces, and thus reduced conductivity/higher thermal losses), and things like degradation of the metal surfaces of the heating, the gate and plates due to electron bombardement. While higher acceleration (i.e. higher plate voltage) would counteract that, it sounds like a "dangerous" thing to try in either case, in the sense that I'd guess that it'd significantly increase the speed of degradation.

Comment: A matched pair of 6JSC6 costs US$75. When you consider the damage that might result from increasing the plate voltage by 33%, stressing other and aged components beyond their specs, this could be a worthwhile investment.

Comment: @PeteNU9W that was a typo sorry i fixed the question.

Comment: @BrianK1LI yes i've done this mod and it's about that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller i didn't understand any of that, so the answer to my question is bad idea ?

Comment: @BrianK1LI but if i replace the tubes with good ones i can still get even more power out of those right ? if i increase the plate voltage ...

Comment: @Andrew if you replace degraded components with good ones, I'd strongly recommend **not** operating the device out of spec. I mean, you risk breaking your freshly repaired amplifier? And if increasing the output power was so easy, the original designers would certainly have done it to begin with.

Comment: I have restored a few old tube-based transceivers (mostly Drake TR3,TR4 types) and I have never taken the approach of hacking the power supply to increase power.  Actually, I replaced the old tube based power supplies (a separate unit) with solid state boards but using the same mechanical box -- even left the old can type electrolytic in place.  Then, I have replaced tubes as needed, cleaned the units, did alignment, and put them into full operating condition.  That is the kind of thing you need to do.  Follow up....

Comment: Continued...increasing the mains power by changing a tap will not only change the plate voltage but every other voltage in the rig.  You are changing grid control voltages, maybe pushing currents beyond tube safe zones, and also affecting critical circuits that are dependent on good voltage control (oscillator).  Not then way to fix the problem you have.

Comment: Further reading indicates the perils of pushing the tubes: increased in-band intermodulation distortion (i.e., not harmonics) which could make you a bad neighbor on the band; increased plate dissipation which could accelerate the decline of the tubes.

Comment: Gentlemen, [comments are not for posting answers to the question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Please post answers and then delete your relevant comment. The op asked `What else would that do?`, and there are several comments above that would make excellent answers.

Answer (score 3):

Should it be confirmed that the old finals are responsible for the low output then there could be only one solution i.e to replace the old finals with new tubes.

Thermionic emission from an old vacuum tube cannot be improved by increasing the plate voltage.